# Fallout 4 main quest length

Tags: fallout-4

I've been playing Fallout four for 20 hours or so and I've been trying to avoid the main quest in fear of the game coming to an end too quickly.

Hopefully, we can avoid spoilers here. I've just talked to V....., and I would like to know if that means I am going to finish the game soon if I stick to the main quest.

I find the main story line very entertaining so I would like to continue it for a while and then go back to secondary stuff for a while.

So, how far am I into the main quest would you say when I meet V.....?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Above half way through the main story but not by much. You can continue doing side quests even after completing the story but [later in the game you're required to make some permanent choices](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/243502/528000).

Answer (score -2):

About 1/4 to half way done dont worry lots comming your way main quest is not short