# Deacon refuses to board Vertibird in 'Rockets' Red Glare' quest

Tags: fallout-4

I think I have the same bug as described [here](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Rockets'_Red_Glare#Bugs):

> "*A glitch may occur if Deacon is wearing power armor where he won't board the Vertibird*".

I think Deacon is injured. He is just sitting by the door. He gave me the explosive charges but he refuses to board the Vertibird. The solution mentioned on the Fandom page is to reload a previous save, but what if I don't have one? I'm playing the game on PC.

Comment: Can you expand on "nobody seems to have exactly the same issue"? What is "the stuff"? Why do you think he is dead or injured?

Comment: "nobody seems to have exactly the same issue": after hours of searching, the only mention of a similar issue is in the fandom bugs, which I linked. "the stuff": the stuff you need for the quest, I forget exactly what he gives you, explosives I think. I think he is injured, not dead. He is sitting by the door.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead *tfc*, I just get close enough and check if it's the right ID with *openactorcontainer 1* ; you'll want that open anyway if you're going to recycle them.

I'd try *enable* and *disable*, or dismissing them and completing the quest w/o them (or just drag them around with [Companion whistle](https://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/13499/)) and then try again, before I tried *resetai* or *recycleactor*, both of which can break quests.

I've had companions stuck in animation loops; never found a solution other than starting a new game, because if I'm going to lose ten hours, what's the difference.

If I really wanted to try and salvage that save, I'd look into where it all went wrong at the specific stage in the quest and 'go back one' :

[How to do one step back in a quest “Molecular Level”?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/281478/how-to-do-one-step-back-in-a-quest-molecular-level)

SetStage <QuestID> <Quest stage number>

and

ResetQuest <QuestID>

"Warning: This command can potentially break a quest, with no way to move forward on that quest."

So again, it's time for a new game or forget about using Deacon for the remainder of this one. Because finding the right quest to mess with can be difficult, and you'll never be sure it didn't break something else.

---

That being said, **the answer *to your specific question* is** in the link.

> This bug can also be fixed by typing the console command **setstage RR303 1300**

---

*But what if you don't have an earlier save?*

Then you haven't gotten into the habit of making a hard save archive every twenty minutes and in between every quick save, which you surely will now I hope. Welcome to the successor of the Gamebryo engine; the Creation Engine, the most pliable and capable engine ever created which is why it breaks so much.

Comment: "The Companion whistle teleports your active Companion to you. It also works with non Companion followers. It does not alter the follow/stay state. This means, if it was in stay mode before teleport, it will be so afterwards too." - Use in conjunction with [AmazingFollowerTweaks](https://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/26976/?tab=description)

Comment: Companion whistle should go in quick slot '2'. Which is the same number to open a companion's inventory through dialogue, so you can jam that button to get at their goodies. AFT goes in slot '3'. And in '1' I have [outfit configurator](https://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/10282/). 'up' and 'right' are all weapons, 'down' is stims, water, then food.

Comment: 'Use in conjunction with AFT', because with that you can set 'catch up upon weapon draw' to off, so they don't magically teleport to you w/o your expressed permission to break immersion.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I was stuck in the minigun of the vertibird. "Get close enough" doesn't really work.The rest of the answer is fantastic though.

Comment: I'd like to think the whistle would've worked, had it been bound to a hotkey. Works in elevators like a champ.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the console (<kbd>`</kbd> key)
2. Enter the command `tfc` to move the camera separately from the player.
3. Leave the console
4. Move the camera (with the wasd keys) over to deacon
5. Enter the console again
6. Click on deacon
7. Enter the command `recycleactor`
8. Enter the command `tfc` to move the camera back to the player
9. Close the console

Comment: Be sure to empty the inventory of Deacon, as `recycleactor` will reset the inventory.

Comment: "you can try "recycleactor", but that may have side effects." – [How do I reset NPCs in Skyrim?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/73205/how-do-i-reset-npcs-in-skyrim)

Comment: Actually, you should empty deacon anyway when going on that quest, it tends to reset his inventory even without any meddling!